# Prove that $\neg(p \wedge q) \Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee \neg q$ using truth table

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Prove that $\neg(p \wedge q) \Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee \neg q$ using truth table

Here is my table but I get a contradiction..

[image]

See, the yellow mark things must be same but they aren't :(

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Check out your third column: what is $0 \wedge 0$ meant to be?

Comment: Ohhh thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You got the definition of $\land$ wrong. In fact, $p \land q = 1$ if and only if both $p = 1$ and $q = 1$. So, $0 \land 0 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you now it will work :D

Answer (score 1):

The rows in the column below the proposition $(p \land q)$ should be $1\;$ *if and only* if both $\;p=1 \land q = 1.\;$ Otherwise, $0$. So only the bottom row in the column below $(p\land q)$ should be $1$.

With that knowledge, all the rows, except the bottom row of the column $\lnot (p\land q)$ should be $1$, with only the bottom row of that column equal to $0$.  The rest is plain to see.

Comment: Side note: the truth values you place in the rows below the column $(p\land q)$ are those that would follow from the connective $\iff$, as in $p\iff q$.